# internet connection drops randomly

Tags: windows, networking

I have 3 PCs at home (with Win XP, Win 7 & Win 7) and a router. I am always connected to the internet through the router (PPoE connection). My problem is that sometimes when I want to search or open a page, my browser tells me that the server cannot be reached, as if I don't have a connection to the internet. Other times it logs me out from messenger, but browsing still works. FTP download/upload also works. If i disable and enable the LAN then all works fine.

The connection **doesn't** always drop on all three PC's at the same time.

Anyone got any idea besides re-installing OS?

thanks

Comment: Is this happening on one, two, or all three PCs?

Comment: WHat happens if you try to ping through the router when it seems down?
(`start->run->"cmd"->"ping 8.8.8.8"` will ping a google DNS server)

Comment: @Fake Name: That doesn't even work for me, and my connection is hunky-dory.

Comment: it's happening on all three PC's

Comment: Reinstalling the OS is probably not a good idea then, because if you have the problem on all PCs, the problem is with your router or your internet connection. Try connectiong with one of your computers directly to the internet, and if the problem is gone, then it's your router that's messing with you.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable and enable the LAN"? Do you unplug the router or dis-/enable the network interfaces on your windows machines?

Comment: Verified the problem is NOT PPPoE keep-alive.

Comment: @Paul Lammertsma - Really? 8.8.8.8 is one of Google's DNS servers, and it uses multiple locations through anycast, the chances of it being down are *really* low.

I can ping it fine. (Are you typing the quotes?)

Comment: @Fake Name: I was only suggesting that not all network infrastructures allow ICMP packets, nor do all hosts respond to them. Try, for example, `ping www.microsoft.com`. I would instead suggest performing a HTTP request; that is sure to pass through any firewalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-installed on oll PC's the OS, it might have been a trojan or something (on all PC's). I have different AV, but none of them found anything... Now it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

Check DHCP settings as well; a lease that doesn't renew till the lease expires will look like a brief connection drop, and will not happen on all three machines at the same time.  Normally, the client starts trying to renew the lease when it is half-way through the lease period.  ipconfig /all will show the lease info, including when the lease was obtained and when it should expire.  If you find that the lease was obtained right after the connection interruption took place, that would be the smoking gun.

Comment: DHCP is always turned off